# Elastic Beanstalk Multicontainer Docker Environments: redirect requests between 2 APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a multicontainer Docker environment on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. This env include 2 APIs container - PHP and node. The reason for that is we have all previously implemented logic and end points in php, however all new end points are made in nodejs. Now I would like to setup redirection that the existence of 2 API containers would be transparent for the client. For example when the client queries server/login it would be redirected to the php container, when server/register to the node one. Thus redirection should be determined based on endpoint. What is the best approach to implement this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach is relative.

Nginx or haproxy in front are your best bet for swapping backends based on URL rules.

Comment: Well, haproxy is a load balancer. There is already load balancer on AWS. Can I use that one instead?

Comment: Ok, I dived a bit into ELB vs HaProxy. You are right. For my particular case the latter is better, since allow to loadbalancing based on urls. I will wait for sometime for other answers and if no better solutions I will mark yours as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: You could put a 3rd app up who's only job is to be HAproxy.
Client -> elb for haproxy -> haproxy instance -> elb for your instance

Comment: you could also look into API gateway: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html